# BLDC : Only half of its coils is active

Tags: brushless-dc-motor

I have a BLDC motor that due to some limitations (mechanical) half of its coils most be removed like the following:

[image]

Now my question is, is this motor just worked? how about performance?

Comment: Are you asking if that would work, or is that something you did and you're asking how it works?

Comment: No, just asking. Did not tested on a real one.

Answer (score 3):

Theoretically it could work, if you know what remains. Three coils should be enough. It will be like a linear motor, just bent to a circle.

But there will be uncompensated force on the rotor in direction perpendicular to it, bearings will suffer.

Although on your picture it looks like the rotor is outside. What are you going to put instead of the coils?

Comment: Nothing, outrunner design has a break like system that force the design to remove some coils. Outrunner section is a wheel in fact.

Comment: Are you designing an electric car? I was thinking about that design for some time...

Comment: By the way, two coils may also be enough.

Comment: Yeah exactly. My car is a front wheel. I can attach a motor to rear wheels but there is no shaft, so this design comes to mind. I can attach more coils, but how performance decreased? for example I have 5 hp motor.

Comment: I would try removing two quarters of coils leaving two opposite sets of coils.

Comment: Performance decrease is linear?

Comment: Define performance. It may remain the same in many aspects.

Comment: ME thinks he would be better with 6 coils, not seven..that is, half of them, otherwise its 2-2-3 which will create quite a bit of torque vibration. That will give him half the torque.

Comment: Agreed. Did i say 7?

Comment: Nope.. I'm just looking at the image and decided to add the comment here since it is a good answer. You may want to add it to the answer in case this discussion gets canned.

Comment: Image is just a sample for illustration. please correct your number relative to coils count. thanks

Comment: @Sampro, if your going to cut it down use a multiple of 3, i.e 3,6 or 9.